# Regex to insert new line character after semicolon and remove names before email

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a list of emails all on one line that I would like to clean up. They are currently in the following format:

```
Jones, Peter <jones.h7@petstore.com>; Bradley, Charles <bradley19@petstore.com>; Frank, Hilda <frank.hl@petstore.com>;
```

and the desired result is as follows:

```
jones.h7@petstore.com;
bradley19@petstore.com; 
frank.hl@petstore.com;
```

So the names and angle brackets around the email are removed.

I would like a regex solution. I have tried replacing `;\s` with `\r\n` but did not get tthe expected result. I am very new to regex so I'm stuck.

Comment: extract all the contents present inbetween `<>` using `<(.*?)>` regex.

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: You can just match anything inside the `<...>` with `<([^<>]+)>;` and get the contents of group 1. Is that enough? Please let us know what language you are using.

Comment: hi, im just using sublime text. To the downvoter, how about a comment on what you think is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing everything but the `<...>`-ed emails, you can just match the mails with one of the following regular expressions (if you really insist on a regex solution):

```
<([^@<>]+@[^@<>]+)>;
```

The email addresses will be in captured group 1. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP0cJ4/1)

If you need to get the string with replacing what you do not need, you may still use

```
<([^@<>]+@[^@<>]+)>(;)|[^<>]+|<|>
```

With `$1$2` replacement string. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cP0cJ4/4)

Comment: Thanks stribizhev, very good answer i must say, i like the demo page :)

Comment: Please be careful with that site as it can only deal with PCRE (PHP/Perl), Python and JavaScript regex flavors. If you are using C#, you should not use that site, but regexstorm.net or regexhero.net. What flavor are you using?

Comment: I have updated the answer so that in case you have `<>` or `<  >` inside with no emails inside, they could also be removed.

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you, or if you need more assistance withtit. If it works, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes, but look-behinds are not supported. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<([^>]*)>(;)|[^><]*
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1$2\n`.Remove empty newlines later.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cK4iV0/27

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex as well:

```
(?:[^<]+)<([^>]+)>(;)
```

and replace it with `$1$2\n`.

Here first group captures email address and second group captures `;`. Here `?:` ignore the name before the email addresses.

#### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW0sR4/2)